# How to get the local file to the resource in the devstool of web browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, autodesk-forge

I want to load the static files from the local by using UseStaticFiles.But it can not load all the file that inside the sub-folder and other type of file.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\code\0223\project_ disconnect V7\wwwroot\javascript\OOO.rvt\output\Resource\3D 視圖\3D-Main 153824"),
    RequestPath = "/OOO.rvt/output/Resource/3D 視圖/3D-Main 153824",
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS");
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    }

});
```

This is my browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tihye.png)

I hope can be like this that I launch with live server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHKUk.png)

How can I do with the .NET Core project and get the same resource?

Comment: Where is your `@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\code\0223\project_ disconnect V7\wwwroot\javascript\JDC_KHH_CT_20220913.rvt\output\Resource\3D 視圖\3D-Main 153824"`? Does it in your current running project `wwwroot/javascript/JDC_KHH_CT_20220913.rvt/output/Resource/3D 視圖/3D-Main 153824` folder?

Answer (score 0):

This setting would cause unexpected results, espectially you run the server on other machines without this path `C:\Users\User\Desktop\code\0223\project_ disconnect V7\wwwroot`.

```js
FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\code\0223\project_ disconnect V7\wwwroot\javascript\JDC_KHH_CT_20220913.rvt\output\Resource\3D 視圖\3D-Main 153824"),
```

If you just want to serve the SVF package in the sub-folder of the wwwroot, it should be enough to use the following, but please ensure to tell the server to handle unknown file types as `application/octet-stream`.

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
    DefaultContentType = "application/octet-stream"
});
```

Besides, when you're following the instructions of the log [Consume AEC data with SVFs on your own server](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/consume-aec-data-svfs-your-own-server), if your SVF packages are not put under the root of wwwroot, please be aware of the path prefix. In your case, it's the `javascript` folder. The `window.location.href` doesn't have this path prefix.

For example, you're requesting SVF file via `http://localhost:3000/javascritp/ZZZ.svf`. The value of `window.location.href` will be `http://localhost:3000/`. Therefore, to fix it, please do the following.

```js
//Change this override from
Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.getItemApi = (endpoint, derivativeUrn, api) => {
    return window.location.href + decodeURIComponent(derivativeUrn.split('urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:')[1]) //decode the URN and extract its path
}

//To this one
Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.getItemApi = (endpoint, derivativeUrn, api) => {
    return window.location.href + '/javascript/' + decodeURIComponent(derivativeUrn.split('urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:')[1]) //decode the URN and extract its path
}
```